# Alphabetic input disabled on Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

Enter and functional inputs(home, end, delete, etc) work fine.
But suddenly all alphabetic inputs on IDE started not working although even Command + C, and Command + V work.

Anyone knows why it suddenly locked a-z + 0-9 inputs?

I tried

1. Clean, Rebuild project and Invalidate Cache.
2. Restart Android Studio and Mac